# SwiperJS Lazy-Loading doesn't load images

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, swiper.js

I've followed these [steps](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#lazy-loading), but the images still won't load. I read somewhere, to load the swiper after the images are loaded. So I init the swiper after the data is successfully received. But are the images already loaded then?

```html
<div class="swiper">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div v-for="image in property.images" :key="image.id" class="swiper-slide">
      <img :data-src="image.filePath" class="swiper-lazy" />
      <div class="swiper-lazy-preloader"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
async fetch() {
  try {
    const property = await this.$axios.$get(
      `/api/get-specific-property/${this.$route.params.id}`
    )

    if (property.success) {
      this.property = property.data
      this.initSwiper()
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
},

methods: {
  initSwiper() {
    Swiper.use([Lazy]) // Not sure if it's really needed - saw this somewhere 
    this.swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
      lazy: true,
      preloadImages: false,
      slidesPerView: 1,
      loop: false,
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't this that you need to have images loaded before the plugin, it's more a matter of the library maybe not working that well with a querySelector? Try out `new Swiper(this.$ref.swiper, {` maybe (don't forget to add it to the template). Do you have any errors in the console? Also, what do you see in the DOM? Are the links for the images correct?

Comment: Refs makes no difference. The images are displayed if I loop the images outside of the swiper with usual :src. So the links are correct. I've no errors in the console, but in the vue devtools swiper shows me, that there are no images to load. 

I think I have to lazy load the images, because otherwise the first image is displayed but the swiper is totally messed up and doesn't work really.

Comment: I don't see a big mistake right now, it should be working. I may give it a try maybe to see if I can find the issue.

Comment: I don't know what happened, but the swiper is now working. I didn't really change anything here, I worked on other places. Should I delete the question?

Comment: No need to delete it, it can help some people at some point IMO.